# Concurrently handling multiple requests from a single client with Netty

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, netty

I am tweaking the basic Netty Discard server example in an effort to understand how Netty deals with concurrent requests from the same connected client. I have the following handler....

```
private static class Handler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, String arg1) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("received " + arg1);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("woke up");
    }
}
```

And the server stood up as follows....

```
public static void run() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1); // (1)
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(3);
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap(); // (2)


        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class) // (3)
         .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() { // (4)
             @Override
             public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(new Handler());
             }
         })
         .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)          // (5)
         .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // (6)

        // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(4744).sync(); // (7)

        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

With the server ran as such...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("heere");
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
        try {
            run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
} here
```

My goal here is to see the Handler ran with multiple threads, indicated by intertwined 'receive' and 'woke up' traffic. I was under the impression that the worker group are the threads that service the request, and I have 3 assigned to it, but I am not seeing the concurrency I expect. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Handler` is blocking the calling thread, which might be OK to simulate a heavy workload (regardless of CPU usage) but Netty is not supposed to run long-lasting tasks in its `EventLoop` because they prevent reuse of the threads that should process inbound messages. Your `run()` method is blocking the caller (with `f.channel().closeFuture().sync()`). The caller is the `main()` method in a `SingleThreadExecutor`. So you are running one server at a time, which accepts one connection at a time.

@Apolozeus' answer is correct in the sense that reducing the sleep delay gets you closer to the behavior that Netty is designed to support.

You want to experiment with concurrent connections from the same client. Unless you write specific code, it doesn't matter if the same client (same remot IP address from server's point of view) or different ones are connecting.

Your code is very weird in the sense that you run a server several times. This shows you that `f.channel().closeFuture().sync()` is a blocking call. You could get a behavior closer to a real application with a single server offloading the "sleep task" to another executor. The "sleep task" should also send some response to the client and close the `Channel`.

Comment: Asker seems to want to service concurrent requests from a single connection, in parallel, not concurrent connections from a single connection.

Answer (score 1):

I just quickly ran your code, and see that there is nothing wrong. It might related on order of running and timing as well. So I would recommend you to change our handler as as per below. Basically, thread name is added and sleep time is reduced to 1 second. Please find below sample output, I can see different requests are handled concurrently by all 3 threads.

```
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, String arg1) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("received " + Thread.currentThread().getName() );
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("woke up " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Output

```
...
received nioEventLoopGroup-3-1
received nioEventLoopGroup-3-2
woke up nioEventLoopGroup-3-1
received nioEventLoopGroup-3-1
woke up nioEventLoopGroup-3-2
received nioEventLoopGroup-3-2
woke up nioEventLoopGroup-3-1
received nioEventLoopGroup-3-1
woke up nioEventLoopGroup-3-2
received nioEventLoopGroup-3-2
received nioEventLoopGroup-3-3
...
```

Comment: received defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1woke up defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1
received defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1
woke up defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1
received defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1
woke up defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1
received defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1
woke up defaultEventExecutorGroup-4-1

Comment: Did you open multiple telnet sessions to the server? I am looking for multiple threads handling input from a connection from one socket.

Comment: Yes, it should be coming from different clients. As one thread will be scheduled to handle incoming requests per connection.

Comment: Ok. So the best way to get the parallelism I want is to make a shallow pipeline with my handler spawning of threads as per.....

Comment: @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String token) throws Exception {    executors.submit( () -> ....) };

Comment: Dang. I am having a heck of a time with formatting.

Comment: Yes, just make sure you shut the executor down once done.